# Simple way to align text within tabbing environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabbing

I want to align text within a `tabbing` environment without using a new environment. That means `flushleft` and `flushright` are not options. Ideally smething like this would be nice:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\textalign[left]{Hello} \= \textalign[center]{There} \= \textalign[right]{World}
\end{tabbing}
```

How do I do this though?

Comment: You can use a `tabular` with `{lcr}`: `\begin{tabular}{lcr}`.

Comment: dont want to use tabular because i need to be able to break across pages

Comment: Oh. Then can I suggest a `longtable` or `ltablex` solution if you don't mind?

Comment: @HarishKumar Already suggested in the answer too :-)

Comment: From [LaTeX Community](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7943): In a tabbing environment using the `\\`` command, which will push the text right aligned up to the next tab stop, or the end of the line if there are no more assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\newcommand\textalign[2][]{%
\ifx#1l\relax
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#2}%
\else
  \ifx#1r\relax
    \makebox[0pt][r]{#2}%
  \else  
    \ifx#1c\relax
      \makebox[0pt][c]{#2}%
    \fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hrulefill

\begin{tabbing}
\=\hspace*{.5\linewidth}\=\hspace{.5\linewidth}\=\kill \\
\> \textalign[l]{Hello} \> \textalign[c]{There} \> \textalign[r]{World} \\
\> \textalign[l]{Longer text} \> \textalign[c]{Another longer text} \> \textalign[r]{Some other text}
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but I don't see much use in this. Some other approaches (e.g., boxes or `tabular` or `longtable`) without the `tabbing` would do the same.